# Share eclipse java project on github

Tags: eclipse, git, github, share

I am trying to push a eclipse java project to github. That is how I am trying to do it:

In the "git repositories" view, I added my repository, I just created on github:
https://github.com/xxx/SpringTest.git

Now I want to share my project to that git repository. I do that by right click on the project -> team -> share project...

I select my repository, but the next button is greyed out. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:** "Next" and "Finish" is greyed out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Egit manual](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide), the Next button is *always* greyed out at this point:

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/4/46/Egit-0.9-getstarted-project-created.png]

You would need to click on `Finish` in order to complete the process.

You just need to be sure you have a git repo already initialized where your project is.

Comment: How can I make sure the git repo is initialized?

Comment: @jan it is best to get to the command-line version (in a shell) and check what if `git log` returns anything.